# How to make this function go on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

Here is the function, I just want it to commit or activate when the form is submited only.
Currently, I have to add `onclick="ShowProgressAnimation();"` to each form, I want to take place when submit is clicked, global setting

```
function ShowProgressAnimation() {
  $("#loading-div-background").css({ opacity: 0.8 });
  $("#loading-div-background").show();
  $(".button-2").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind it to the `submit` event of the form:

```
$('.form-selector').on('submit', function(eventObject) {
    ShowProgressAnimation();
}
```

Just be careful that your form will be submitted, won't it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your form has an ID `#myForm` for simplicity:

```
form = document.getElementById('myForm');
form.onsubmit = ShowProgressAnimation;
```

If not, it can be accessed from `document.forms`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(){
            ShowProgressAnimation();
            submit(this);
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: `submit(this); return false;` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I could be wrong here but I think you need `return false;` for IE 6. So it's not "completely unnecessary" but close to.

Comment: @p_strand: Isn't the point of the magical jQuery to fix quirks like those? "One code for all browsers"? Seems rather hackish to me.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Agreed. I guess they consider IE 6 to be a legacy browser. I remember distinctly that I had this issue on a project that I worked on that had IE 6 compatibility as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want this to apply to all forms when they are submitted you could add the following to a `.js` file that is included by each page:

```
$(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        ShowProgressAnimation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Appreciate all the feedback, this seems to be right up the alley:$(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        ShowProgressAnimation();
    });
});

Comment: Add this Created this feature.  Have a Onclick on submit button. But would like to add a if statement of valdation success or error then go forth.                                                $(function  ShowProgressAnimation(){
     
    $("form").submit(function(){
      
    $("#loading-div-background").css({ opacity: 0.8 });
    $("#loading-div-background").show();
    $('input[type="submit"]').addClass("disabled");
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
                        
     });
    });

Comment: @FanHitz I'm not sure that I'm following. You say that this worked as you had asked for in the question, but you now want to add form validation to this functionality? Please create a new question for this as it is a rather large topic by itself and please specify what type of form validation you want i.e. does it need to executed on the server-side or on the client-side? I would also assume that you wish this form validation to be general for all forms, since you wanted this function to be triggered for all forms.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Created this feature, there is Onclick="Showprogressanimation" on submit button.   But would like to add check for for error, if not form errors then submit...

```
            $(function  ShowProgressAnimation(){

            $("form").submit(function(){

            $("#loading-div-background").css({ opacity: 0.8 });
            $("#loading-div-background").show();
            $('input[type="submit"]').addClass("disabled");
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');

                });
            });
```

Here is valdation code to combine in statement, I would like to add these two tags to see if they are showing error then do not submit, but if good goahead an submit.

How would I write that in

```
            jQuery("#TxtAccountUserId").validate({

             });

            jQuery("#TxtAccountPassword").validate({

             });
```